# Angular 4 | Interpolation multiple condition statement

Tags: angular, typescript, interpolation

Good day,

How can i do multiple condition in angular 4?

This code below returns only the true ang false, and i want to know if how can i achieve multiple condition statement like. 
`apidata.Operator == null: 'New';` `apidata.Operator == passed: 'Pass';` `apidata.Operator == 'john': 'John';` something like these.

```
{{ apidata.Operator == null ? 'New' : apidata.Operator }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do Like the below code

{{moduletemo1data==null ? '-' : moduletemo1data|number:'1.2-2'}}